Calculate $\alpha$. in the trangle $ABC$
Calculate $\alpha$. (Answer:$30^o$)

My Attempt :
$ \angle DAB \cong \angle DCA = 45^ o$
$\triangle CDB_{(isosc)}: \angle CDB \cong \angle CBD = 90^o -\frac{\alpha}{2}$
$ \triangle ADC: \angle ADC =180^o -(45^o -\alpha)-\alpha = 135^o $
$ \angle ABD = 90^o - (90^o -\frac{\alpha}{2}) = \frac{\alpha}{2}$
I needed to demonstrate that $AB=BD$

You have many typos in the part where you shared your own progress.

As Euclid's comment above indicates, your question has several typos. Note that, in my answer, I used the correct value of $\measuredangle ADC = 135^{\circ}$ versus your $\angle AD\color{red}{B} = 135^o$. Also, I believe you generally prefer more geometric solutions, mine using the law of sines is I hope relatively straightforward & simple enough that I hope it's satisfactory if nobody comes up with a different solution. Nonetheless, I will see if I can come up with one, hopefully quite elegant, that doesn't use the law of sines or anything else like that.

@JohnOmielan  Thanks for help my friend...I really prefer more geometric solutions than trigonometric ones, but I don't see any other alternative for the question. The preference for geometric solutions is because the question is from a geometry book where trigonometry is not used. In most cases, auxiliary lines are used... Thanks for the heads up..I made the correction.

@Euclid Thanks for the heads up..I made the correction.

@petaarantes You're welcome. Also, thanks for explaining about the reason for your preference of more geometric solutions. Note that, as explained in Wikipedia's Law of sines article, the proof for this law involves more geometric mechanisms, in particular using the triangle's circumcircle. As such, I could have used the underlying basis instead, but that would make it longer & more complicated. Instead, I was also looking for different auxiliary lines to add, but where it doesn't overly complicate the solution, as I did with my ...

@petaarantes (cont.) answer to your fairly recent question. However, the several approaches I tried just lead to quite messy results. I doubt there's any method using auxiliary line(s) & a more geometric approach that's even about relatively simple and straightforward as it is to use the law of sines with your problem, much less more simple & straightforward.

@JohnOmielan Don't worry...your resolutions using trigonometry are also very useful...geometric resolutions are just a preference and are not essential. Euclides managed to visualize an interesting resolution.

For simpler algebra, let
$$\lvert BA \rvert = \lvert BC \rvert = \lvert CD \rvert = x \;\;\to\;\; \lvert AC \rvert = \sqrt{2}x$$
Next, we just need to use your result of $\measuredangle ADC = 135^{\circ}$, the Law of sines in $\triangle ADC$, and that $0 \lt \alpha \lt 45^{\circ}$, to get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{\sin(\measuredangle CAD)}{\lvert CD \rvert} & = \frac{\sin(\measuredangle CAD)}{\lvert AC \rvert} \\
\frac{\sin\alpha}{x} & = \frac{\sin(135^{\circ})}{\sqrt{2}x} \\
\sin\alpha & = \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\sin\alpha & = \frac{1}{2} \\
\alpha & = 30^{\circ}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$


First notice that we obtain an angle of $45^\circ$ when we extend $[AD$ as shown in the figure above.
In the isosceles triangle $\triangle CBD$, let the angle bisector of $C$ meet $AD$ at point $E$, as shown in the figure below.

Both points $C,E$ are on the perpendicular bisector of segment $[BD]$; hence, points $B$ and $D$ are symmetric with respect to line $CE$. This gives $\angle CBE = \angle CDE = 45^\circ$.

Now if we look at our original isosceles right triangle $\triangle BAC$, we notice that $E$ lies on the angle bisector of $\angle ABC$, which is the perpendicular bisector of segment $[AC]$. Therefore, $\triangle EAC$ is isosceles as well.

This gives $\angle EAC = \angle ECA \ \Longrightarrow \ \alpha = 45^\circ - \dfrac\alpha2 \ \Longrightarrow \ \boxed{\alpha = 30^\circ}$.

Excellent...very well thought out..Thank you
